# post запрос из silverlight C#

Tags: c#, html, post

Помогите передать в JS, находящийся в index.html, post запрос из C# silverlight содержащий строку "hello world"?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Есть Silverlight проект, по клику на HyperlinkButton нужно передать некоторые данные ("Hello world!") методом POST в проект ASP.NET (который содержится в том же solution), а конкретно в файл index.html содержащий код JavaScript. Сейчас это выглядит следующим образом - я к NavigateUri (в HyperlinkButton) забиндил формирующийся GET запрос (localhost***\index.html?HelloWorld!), а в index.html считал его с помощью JS - location.search и вывел куда нужно. Вот, нужно GET запрос переделать в POST.